# Clearing out selected value for ngx-mat-select-search

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using the `"ngx-mat-select-search"` npm package for angular and I am looking to provide the users of my application with a default "None" option, or after selecting an item, I would want to give the user the ability to clear out the item and have the dropdown return to its original state with only the placeholder of the input displaying.

As of now, when I select an item from the `ngx-mat-select-search` I cannot seem to find a way to remove that item and clear out the selection. Is there some way I can do this, maybe I am missing something?

Here is the link to the documentation/demo of the `ngx-mat-select-search` - [click here](https://stackblitz.com/github/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). As you can see, once an item is selected, there seems to be no way of removing it.

Any help and/or recommendations would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: Based on the documentation, can you specify which type of `mat-select` you're after? Is it a simple select, or a multiple selection select?

Comment: Hi, it is a simple select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I've done this is to just put in a dummy "None" selection as a separate `<mat-option>`.

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select [formControl]="bankCtrl" placeholder="Bank" #singleSelect>
  <mat-option>
    <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="bankFilterCtrl"></ngx-mat-select-search>
  </mat-option>

  <mat-option>None</mat-option>

  <mat-option *ngFor="let bank of filteredBanks | async" [value]="bank">
    {{bank.name}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Because it has no value, when you select it, it just goes back to the placeholder.

This is the same method that the Material team recommends in their [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) and in their corresponding [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/oeeoxjrbygp?file=app%2Fselect-reset-example.ts).

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for, I just wasn't exactly sure where inside of the mat-form-field to place the "None" mat-option.  I believe you could also do it like this: <mat-option [value]="null">None</mat-option>